# Where can i get z3py tutorials

Tags: z3, z3py

rise4fun z3py is unavailable from several weeks due to some security issues. I tried to find out some resources for learning z3py but ended in vain. Please suggest some resources to learn z3py

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I am not asking to find some tool for me. The official page of z3 has provided stackoverflow as one of the means to contact . see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/old/mail.html .

Comment: "Please suggest some resource" is a request to recommend or find something. The fact that the official page sends you here doesn't automatically make off-topic posts become on-topic. The guidelines **here** say that your question is off-topic. See the [On Topic Page](http://stackoverflow/help/on-topic), particularly the numbered list on that page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a zip file with the Z3Py tutorials sources. 
It is basically a few HTML pages and a bunch of python files.
Here is the link:
https://github.com/leodemoura/leodemoura.github.com/blob/master/files/z3py.zip?raw=true

**Update (Jan 14, 2014)**: the Z3Py tutorials are back online

Comment: Z3Py seems to be down again. I downloaded your files and populated the html files with the examples (I found it annoying to keep having to refer to the .py files). These can be downloaded here http://dropproxy.com/f/834

Answer (score 0):

The [official](http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorial) `z3py` tutorials website has been [taken down due to security problems](https://z3.codeplex.com/workitem/112) and is still unavailable at the time of writing of this post.

Meanwhile you can access a mirror of the website containing all the files at [github](https://github.com/ericpony/z3py-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Wayback Machine to see tutorials such as http://web.archive.org/web/20121117183725/http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorialcontent/advanced