# How to define a matrix?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

It looks like Microsoft completely pooched their "rise4fun" website and the [Z3 Python tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorial) no longer loads.

How can I define define a matrix in Z3 for Python and impose some constraints on it?

Comment: what is this site used for (raise4fun) I don't understand anything from it ?

Comment: FYI, the tutorials are available at a link from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002135/where-can-i-get-z3py-tutorials/20005713#20005713 and you may want to look at this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599030/z3-performing-matrix-operations

Comment: thanks, sounds good. I must reasearch about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example:  9x9 matrix of integer variables

```
X = [ [ Int("x_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(9) ] 
  for i in range(9) ]
```

Example: some constraints for the matrix X

```
cells_c  = [ And(1 <= X[i][j], X[i][j] <= 9) 
         for i in range(9) for j in range(9) ]
```

Comment: Hi, now the Z3Py online is returning.  All the best.